# Deleting lines with specific criteria using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code on another post that will single out a line - but it deletes all others EXCEPT the specified line.

I work with large numbers of address lists and I need something I can run that will identify and delete rows with addresses that we've been asked not to mail to. I've just discovered VBA some I'm extremely green. But I'd like to have a module that allows me to add multiple addresses as the list grows.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

   Dim i as long, LastRow As long
   with activesheet
       LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

       For i =  LastRow to 2 step -1

           If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "certain value" Then

              .Rows(i).Delete

           End If

       Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this:

`If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "certain value" Then` - where cell value different then "certain value"

to this:

`If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "certain value" Then` - where cell value equal to "certain value"

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1).value = "certain value" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Union to gather the qualifying rows in one go and delete. Also, have a separate sheet where you store the addresses to match on. Read those addresses into an array, then loop the sheet where data is to be deleted from and check whether a given address is found in your array. If found, use Union to store that cell for later deletion.
At the end of looping the data to check, delete the rows associated with the stored cells in the union'd range object in one go.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DeleteThemRows()
    Dim arr(), unionRng As Range, i As Long, lastRow As Long, rng As Range
    Dim wsAddress As Worksheet, wsDelete As Worksheet

    Set wsAddress = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Addresses")
    Set wsDelete = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataToDelete")

    With wsAddress                               '<= Assume addresses stored in column A starting from cell A1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lastRow
        Case 1
            ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("A1").Value
        Case Is >= 2
            arr = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
        End Select
        arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 1)
    End With

    With wsDelete  '<==Assume address column to check is column A

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim loopRange As Range
        Set loopRange = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(loopRange) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        For Each rng In loopRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng.Value, arr, 0)) Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = rng
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

You could use `Debug.Print unionRng.Address` first to check what will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FastDelete()

    Dim rng As Range, rngData As Range, rngVisible As Range
    Const CRITERIA$ = "SOME_VALUE"

    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion '//Whole table
    With rng '//Table without header
        Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With

    '// Filter by column "A"
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CRITERIA
    On Error Resume Next '//In case if no values filtered
    Set rngVisible = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Err = 0 Then
        rngVisible.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```